# typescript error TS2305: Module "constants" has no exported member

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, react-typescript

I have Vite + React + TypeScript app with structure

```
src
  constants
    a.ts
    b.ts
    index.ts
  components
    Comp.tsx
```

**tsconfig** with `"baseUrl": "src"`

**a.ts** content:

```
export const ARRAY = [1, 2, 3];
```

**b.ts** content:

```
export const Object = { foo: 'bar' };
```

**index.ts** content:

```
export * from './a';
export * from './b';
```

**Comp.tsx** content:

```
import { ARRAY } from 'constants';
```

App works correctly, but in the WebStorm there is an error in **Comp.tsx**:

```
TS2305: Module  "constants"  has no exported member  ARRAY
```

Why? How can I fix it?

I want to get rid of this error.

Comment: It may affiliate with the project and Typescript path setup. The `constants` itself is a reserved word for the node types lib. Therefore, it can be conflicted if you do not explicitly define the proper path to the `constants` directory in your project. The best and easiest way to solve this issue is to avoid using it directly as a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `constants` itself is a reserved word for the node types lib *(Usually reside in this path: `node_modules/@types/node/constants.d.ts`)*. Therefore, it can be conflicted if you do not explicitly define the proper path to the `constants` directory in your project configs.

#### How to fix it?

You have two ways to fix this issue:

1. The best and easiest way to solve this issue is to avoid using `constants` as a direct directory in your project. You can either move it under the `utils` directory *(It mostly depends on your project design and architecture)*, or you can rename it to other custom names such as `consts`, `localConstants`, etc.
2. Explicitly define the exact path for your project's `constants` directory within the [`compilerOptions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#compilerOptions) settings. In your case, you can define it in `tsconfig.*` (JS-based projects can be configured in the `jsconfig.*`).

   According to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) you can do this like below:

   ```json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "paths": {
          "constants": ["./src/constants"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```